# Uploading image url to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

When I try to upload an image onto firebase, the image url is something like "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw@f6699b3" instead of "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...". The image itself uploads to Firebase Storage just fine, but issue right now is with the imageUrl in Realtime Database.

Below is my addToDatabase method.

```
private void addToDatabase(String familyName, String titleTxt, String descrptnTxt, String pointsTxt, String status) {
        if(mImageUri != null){
            StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            String choreId = mRootRef.child("FamilyFunctions").child(familyName).child("Chores").push().getKey();
                            Chores chore = new Chores(assignedTo, descrptnTxt, choreId, mStorageRef.getDownloadUrl().toString(), pointsTxt, status, titleTxt);
//                            Chores chore = new Chores(titleTxt, descrptnTxt, pointsTxt, status, choreId, taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString(), assignedTo);
                            mRootRef.child("FamilyFunctions").child(familyName).child("Chores").child(choreId)
                                    .setValue(chore).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Chore successfully created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }else{
                                                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error. Couldn't add chore.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Below is my chores model:

```
public class Chores {

    public String assignedTo;
    public String description;
    public String id;
    public String imageUrl;
    public String pointsWorth;
    public String status;
    public String title;

    public Chores() {
    }

    public Chores(String assignedTo, String description, String id, String imageUrl, String pointsWorth, String status, String title) {
        this.assignedTo = assignedTo;
        this.description = description;
        this.id = id;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.pointsWorth = pointsWorth;
        this.status = status;
        this.title = title;
    }

//getters and setters etc.
//...
}
```

I have tried other methods of writing `"mStorageRef.getDownloadUrl().toString()"` and changing it to `taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl()` but so far nothing else has worked, and I'm trying to avoid rewriting all of my code. Can someone please help me??

Comment: getDownloadUrl returns a Task just like putFile, not the URL.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).